# Azure AD B2C - my app has Businesses and their Employees

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to create a custom login form with Azure B2C, primarily because I need every registered user to be approved. So I created a lib which has `CreateUser` method and it uses Graph API to do so. Now, I see `jobTitle`, `department`, `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` properties for a User (**[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity)**) but I don't see a **Company Name**!

I've found **TenantDetail Entity** at the same page and I'd like to know how are they related and should I create this `TenantDetail Entity` first and then associate new users to it?

As a reminder, this is just for having multiple users in my app which may work for a different companies (businesses).

Consequently, I may have *Edit user details* page later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "TenantDetail" entity contains details for the Azure AD tenant rather than users.

You should create a custom attribute for representing the company name for a registered user as described at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr).

You can get and set this custom attribute for the user objects using the Graph API as documented at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet#use-custom-attributes).